# Gradle copySpec: replaceToken for regex pattern

Tags: regex, gradle, filter, copy

Gradle copySpec: how to replaceToken for regex pattern?

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
   from ("/path/to") {
      include "*.txt"

      filter (ReplaceTokens, tokens : ["Hello(.+)World" : replacement]
   }

}
```

Regular expressions are not supported for the ReplaceToken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ReplaceTokens](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.html) filter does not support regexes, just replacing fixed tokens with a prefix and a suffix.

To use a regex, you can for example use `filter { it.replaceAll(/Hello(.+)World/, replacement) }`.

Be aware that you should also set a `filteringCharset`, so that the files are handled with the correct encoding and not depending on the default charset of the JVM / OS you run the build on.

Comment: the pattern is not a quoted string? Tried with java code to remove multi-line comments: filter { it.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", "") }, not working. thanks.

Comment: two back slashes is shown as one. the pattern works in java SE.

Comment: also tried: it.replaceAll(/(?s)\/\*.*?\*\//, "")

Comment: "it" is one line, or whole file content?

Comment: After debugging, "it" is one line, not working for multi-line comments. Is there a way to replace multi-line pattern in the whole file content? thanks.

Comment: Resolved using eachFile. Your answer works for line by line. Accepted as answer.